# Initializing private repositories on production server

Tags: git, repository, cvs, git-branch, dev-to-production

What I want to do now is to initialize a private repository on my production server in to app's www folder (ex: /var/www/app.com/web/) and then clone it as a staging repository to my testing site (ex: /var/www/test.com/web/app.com/) and finaly clone from staging to local to work with the code.

Am I planning it the right way?

I am following these tutorials to learn more about setting the "git server" and initialize private repositories:

- http://progit.org/book/ch4-4.html
- https://moocode.com/posts/6-code-your-own-multi-user-private-git-server-in-5-minutes
- http://www.layeredthoughts.com/git/private-remote-git-repositories-ubuntu-linode

One last question, this tutorial about A Successful Git Branching Model where would apply? On the main private repository (production server), local, or mixed? I haven't read it completely yet, I'll do it asap.

EDIT:

- If it matters, I am trying to do so on a server running ISPConfig configuration.
- It's not a must to work/be as mentioned above, if there is a "healthier" way... glad to learn about it.

This http://www.howtoforge.com/the-perfect-subversion-server-debian-lenny-ispconfig-3 and this http://www.howtoforge.com/installing-subversion-and-configuring-access-through-different-protocols-on-ubuntu-11.10 to GIT version is what I kinda had in mind

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Am I planning it the right way?

The cascading repos sounds quite complex, and is not normal.

Consider any checkout a client/satelite/child of the bare git repo you are committing to. Your staging and production installs should be read-only checkouts of specific branches, you are perhaps already familiar (because almost all git questions get a link to it - this question now being no exception) with [git-flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) which may give some insight into how to setup your branches and therefore checkouts appropriately.

**Git Server Setup**

[This tutorial](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server) is probably the only one you need to follow.

Note that if you setup the git user with a home at `/home/git` and create a repo at `/home/git/project.git` that means you don't need absolute paths. I.e.

```
(server) $ cd /home/git
(server) $ mkdir project.git
(server) $ cd project.git
(server) $ git --bare init
```

Then wherever you want it:

```
(home) $ git clone git@server:project.git
```

of course, you could also put your git repos wherever you want and just change the git user's home dir (in `/etc/passwd`) to achieve the same.

**Update on push**

If you want to update a checkout whenever you push to a repository, you need a post-receive hook to do it. First set your self up correctly:

```
(server) $ cd /var/www/app.com/web/
(server) $ git clone -b production-branch /home/git/project.git . # it's local - use a file path
(server) $ cd /var/www/test.com/web/app.com/
(server) $ git clone -b staging-branch /home/git/project.git .
```

Then create /home/git/project.git/hooks/post-update with

```
cd /var/www/test.com/web/app.com
git --git-dir /var/www/test.com/web/app.com/.git pull #> /dev/null 2>&1 & #uncomment after testing
```

Ensure that:

- The hook file is executable and owned by git
- Git is (also) in the same group as the owner of the checked out files otherwise you'll get permission errors when you push

As written above the output of the command will be sent to you every time you push, which will make pushing slow(ish). You can run it in the background when you're sure it works correctly. It won't matter that staging checkout is pulling on every push - if there's no changes to the branch it's pointing at, it won't do anything.

It's probably not a good idea to update your live site automatically. Instead

```
(home) $ git checkout production-branch
(home) $ git merge staging-branch
(home) $ git push # updating production-branch
(home) $ git checkout feature/i-was-working-on-this
(home) $ ssh server 'cd /var/www/app.com/web/; git pull'
# Manual Post update checks
```

If you did that automatically and for example the update left your production site in an unusable state - you may not know (until/unless you get a [pingdom](http://www.pingdom.com) alert saying "Production site offline"). It would be safe to automate updating your live site if you've got significant test coverage and an automated deploy process - but walk before running :).

**Direct push**

You can if you really want to push into a not-bare checkout if you set

```
[receive]
    denyCurrentBranch = ignore
```

In the project's .git/config file, if there are no local changes that should also update the  working copy (iirc).

Comment: definitely an amazing answer AD7six, thank you master :) If it's not a good idea to update the site automatically, what other options are there? As I mentioned in the edit, this is meant for an ISPConfig environment (if you know it).

Comment: I don't remember anything specific about ISP config that would change the above

Comment: tnx a lot for the info. Sorry but I can't help my self not asking: You working for Pingdom? xDD

Comment: no I don't - it's just a way of explaining that your site went offline and you didn't realize. If gitolite offers something you need - sure. Do you have multiple users and want fine-grained permission control? if not, then you don't need gitolite. Incidentally 2 successive comments -> edit, or delete and merge the old comment into the new.

Comment: I wonder: do you think there is a better way of doing the mentioned in the question?

Comment: "this tutorial" link is dead, http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server

Comment: @Jeremey thanks, updated. (you could also have edited the answer to correct the link).

Answer (score 2):

It's good idea, but requires a bit more work.

Git will not update working copy when you push to a non-bare repo unless you help it by defining a [`post-update` hook](http://schacon.github.com/git/githooks.html) to do `git reset --hard` when the checked-out branch is pushed to, plus disabling the default check against pushing to checked out branch (I don't remember the exact option, look in [git-config](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-config.html) man page).

Note, that doing `git reset --hard` will undo any local modification. Writing the hook so it preserves local modification is a little more tricky, but can also be done. However, you shouldn't have local modification on the production server, right?

With appropriate hook in place, it's quite sensible workflow for small setup, when you don't have many servers.

For larger setup I'd have a bare repository on separate server and the hook would cause a `git pull` to run on the production repo using an `ssh trigger`. Advantage is that you would have the central repo on server not accessible from outside and thus could better secure it.

Comment: I'm still learning git, isn't it possible to start a bare repository on the production server, so I won't have the mentioned problem?

Comment: @w0rldart: It absolutely does not matter where the bare repository is,  though I'd prefer a server in internal network over one in demilitarized zone (where production servers live, thus not production server). But I assumed you want to automatically update the data your production server serves when you push. And that will require a `post-update` hook in any case. You can have a non-bare repository that you push to with `post-update` hook to fix up it's working directory or a bare repository with `post-update` hook to update a non-bare one, but in either case you need a `post-update` hook.

Comment: @w0rldart: A setup with a bare and non-bare repository, while taking up more space will probably be a bit safer to set up and easier to back up and such, so yes, that would do.