# Using Git Flow, the successful branching model

Tags: git, version-control, branch, git-flow

I joined a project and they kinda have a chaos for code testing and version control solution, so I am in charge of implementing those and more.

Me, being relatively new to Git, I was wondering how should I implement the http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/ ? And by that I mean:

- Should I setup the git repository using `git flow init` on the LAMP server (where all the testing and version control will be held)?
- How do I push some changes to a specific `feature_x` / `hotfix_y` / `releas_z` branch in the remote repository?
- Should I have the same `git flow init` setup, on my local cloned repository?

I have a basic knowledge of git, so I would appreciate your guidance on this.

### UPDATE

If you know a better solution on how to use a control version system and be able to sync from local to live and/or testing environment, please let me know... I'm willing to learn

Comment: FWIW, my team adopted that same branching model but does not use git flow at all.

Comment: as I suppose you know, `git-flow` it's just a collection of scripts that are meant to help the use of the `successful branching model`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

git-flow is not something you ordinarily run on your remote server, and is merely a tool to aide managing branches. You would only run `git flow init` on not-bare checkouts where someone is going to be doing development work. So, in order:

- No, you'd just create a bare git repo (using git flow doesn't fundamentally change how to use git)
- With `git push` (or, the first time only with: `git push --set-upstream origin feature/name-of-current-feature` - this is also in the error message in the current version of git trying to push on a branch not tracking anything)
- Yes

Comment: do you know a better solution on how to use a control version system and be able to sync from local to live and/or testing environment?

Comment: I'd say use git-flow until you find something about it that you want to do differently (by which time you'll be confident enough with git to decide how to do that). having your live site pull from master, and your test/dev site pull from develop is quite normal from my perspective.

Comment: oh, I understand... thanks for the advice, and just so you know... I was making a reference to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9431741/initializing-private-repositories-on-production-server

Comment: I didn't realize you were the same author :]