# Is setuping gitosis, or similar tools, really worth it?

Tags: git, version-control, gitolite, gitosis

Just as the title says, is it worth it going for a `gitosis` or `gitolite` setup instead of a simple `git` server setup?

Or, will it have any benefits in the future when I'll have more people pushing commits to that server?

Comment: Do your users yet have their login, rights, public keys set on the server ? Are they able to access your server using ssh ? If not, gitosis may simplify the administrative task.

Comment: Yes, they were able... now I'm building a new server, and that's why I'm asking

Comment: Maybe you could go for `gitolite`, it seems to have more features.
Comparison is maid in this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888300/gitosis-vs-gitolite

Comment: Downvoters, please explain why!

Comment: @w0rldart Don't pay too much attention to one downvote. I guess it's probably because the question doesn't seem very constructive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gitosis (or the more recent gitolite) makes it easy to use a git server for users not really used to linux and ssh and not having their own access.

If they're used to linux and they have to access the server for other reasons, and everybody has his own public repository on the server and everybody just pull from other repositories and push to his own ones, you don't really need gitosis. In this case, it's mainly an additional layer that you may avoid.

Comment: I just have a user called `git` which in it's home folder has the bare repositories, and then I have the ssh keys for the people allowed to work there. Just exactly the way is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9431741/initializing-private-repositories-on-production-server

Comment: In fact, git allows you to build the construct of your choice, if everybody in the team understands *what* git does. My usual solution is that every user has his own public repository on the server, in his home, in which he is the only one to push and from where every coder can fetch. You might prefer a more centralized solution but that's simply a choice.

Comment: Ok I see. Yes, I do want a more centralized way of doing things... and it seams that for now I'll keep it the 'simple' way of just using `git`